# occasionally connection timeout from lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm not sure why, but from time to time - once in 20 lambda calls, I receive an error:

```
Connection timed out after 120000ms
```

the calls are done from ECS container, and all (caller and lambda) are written in node.js.

what should I check?

[image]

Comment: Memory leaks? Have you think to X-Ray to inspect your code timing?

Comment: memory leak in the calling app? the calling app is kind of a cron job that execute lambdas. i dont know this service actually

Comment: I thought about memory leak in the Lambda.

Comment: that's what i don't understand. this error comes from the *calling* app

Comment: This isn't "from lamdda function" it is from the AWS API that your code is calling, in an attempt to invoke a Lambda function. You need to look at your networking issues on the ECS side.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old post, but I'll write how I solved a situation with the same error message in a lambda that I was working on. I hope this helps someone with a similar issue.

In my case, I also have a web app inside an EC2 which calls a lambda through `lambda.invoke()` (npm aws-sdk). Both EC2 and lambda runs on Node.JS. Even though the error is logged inside the EC2, the message is thrown by the lambda itself to the caller (EC2).

My lambda makes ~3,000 requests to an API, what takes ~5 minutes (300,000 ms) to get all responses back. It seems that the lambda Node.JS runtime is keeping a socket alive during the lambda execution, which is higher than 120,000 ms (2 minutes). As the lambda code keeps running for more than this threshold, the runtime throws the error, and the lambda return a callback with it.

According to [aws js sdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html#constructor-property), the AWS object has one parameter for the http timeout:

> **httpOptions (map)** — A set of options to pass to the low-level HTTP request. Currently supported options are:
>
> - **timeout [Integer]** — Sets the socket to timeout after timeout milliseconds of inactivity on the socket. Defaults to two minutes (120000).

After I changed this configuration to 360,000 ms (6 minutes), the lambda executes successfully. So you can just set this parameter to a higher value, according to your needs:

```
AWS.config.update({httpOptions: {timeout: 360000}});
```

Answer (score 0):

for me it was not ocassionally, but like for one time to another :S.
Somehow, one of my network devices was deactivated (PANGP Virtual Ethernet Adapter), so I re-activated it worked out
Best!
[image]