# AWS CDK unstable deployment of Lambda CustomResource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

I use cdk to deploy my AWS stack. It's NextJS app with RDS instance. Initialization Database I do using CustomResource approach (Lambda build from Docker image) as suggested that [Article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/use-aws-cdk-to-initialize-amazon-rds-instances/)
Sometimes my deployment fails with error message

```
Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned: Connection timed out after 120000ms
```

Im sure because my database init takes to much time. I do filling the database with "INSERT INTO" SQL queries that repeat about 5000 times.

Could you advise how to avoid that error because deployment script is unstable and I can't rely on it? Many thanks.

Comment: Please add your code - both CDK and lambda. `Connection timed out` suggests that the lambda couldn't connect to the DB. Are you sure the custom resource depends on the DB?

Comment: All code is identical to the Article. Connection to DB establishes correctly, I checked this in a few ways. I guess that the problem occurs that Lambda executes more than 2 minutes and CDK or something breaks the connection. Sometimes my deployment works correctly.

Comment: What's the function timeout? Does increasing it work?

Comment: Timeout of the function "ResourceInitializerFn". Increasing of function timeout doesn't work. I read that this message means timeout of cdk connection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60537114/436694

Comment: Try making your `AwsSdkCall` do `invokeAsync` instead of `invoke`. The deployment will not wait for it to complete, though.

Comment: Did you figure it out?